# How do I reference multiple interface files in a Typescript project using Webstorm IDE?

Tags: javascript, typescript, webstorm

I have imported many class files and many interface files into a WebStorm Typescript project.

How can I handle references for the case where one class (single file) references multiple interfaces (multiple files)?

Do I need to have many references to each of the interface files at the top of each class (file)?

Note that I am using Webstorm. I am not sure if this is different but previously I was working on a Typescript application in Visual Studio and I don't recall any reference links being needed at the top of each of the files that contained my classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> am not sure if this is different but previously I was working on a Typescript application in Visual Studio and I don't recall any reference links being needed at the top of each of the files that contained my classes.

You can use the good old `reference` file trick : https://github.com/TypeStrong/grunt-ts#reference

Comment: Thank you for this good suggestion. Can you tell me with the latest version 9 of WebStorms is there a way for the grunt file to be run automatically or should I just run that after each change to keep everything updated?

Comment: two options: you can use grunt-watch : this makes the process completely out of hands of webstorm (and better for community as they can use whatever ide they want) OR you want use the file watcher in Webstorm to run a command like `grunt ts:dev`

Answer (score 0):

I have been doing it like:

```
import IInterface1 = require('./IInterface1');
import IInterface2 = require('../IInterface2');

class Class1 implements IInterface1, IInterface2 {

}
```

Comment: There must be a simpler way. I have 30+ class files and 20+ interface files. With Visual Studio I had no references at all and it all just worked with intellisense from each interface.

Comment: I think i have read that people might create a master include file.  Where they reference all there file in that and then just have to include that one file everywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

You can create master-reference file in a next manner (mymodule.ts):

```
export import IInterface1 = require('./IInterface1');
export import IInterface2 = require('../IInterface2');
```

and use it:

```
import mod = require('./mymodule');

export function foo(v: mod.IInterface1) {
}
```

This trick - 'export import' does not described in official TS docs, but works fine